# Change only duplicate items but not the original one

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I am trying to change only the duplicate elements of the list and not the original ones but i am not sure how it's done. What I need is only the duplicate elements of a list to change through the dictionary but not the original that appears first. The way I did it below, the original ones change too. I want it to work for every kind of list and not just the particular one.

```
c = 'Paul is 28 years old. Mary is 30 years old. Paul is a lawyer. Mary is a doctor'
lst = c.split(' ')
d = {'Paul': 'Thomas','Mary':'Smith' }

for key,value in d.items():
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] in d.keys():
            lst[i] = d.get(lst[i])

print(lst)

out: ['Thomas', 'is', '28', 'years', 'old.', 'Smith', 'is', '30', 'years', 'old.', 'Thomas', 'is', 'a', 'lawyer.', 'Smith', 'is', 'a', 'doctor']
```

But I want something like this

```
['Paul', 'is', '28', 'years', 'old.', 'Mary', 'is', '30', 'years', 'old.', 'Thomas', 'is', 'a', 'lawyer.', 'Smith', 'is', 'a', 'doctor']
```

Comment: What is the end result you are expecting?

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and output?

Comment: I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether you have seen the name before. And your code can use a lot of simplification:

```
c = 'Paul is 28 years old. Mary is 30 years old. Paul is a lawyer. Mary is a doctor'
lst = c.split(' ')
d = {'Paul': 'Thomas','Mary':'Smith' }
seen = set()

for i, name in enumerate(lst):
    if name in d:
        if name in seen:
            lst[i] = d[name]
        else:
            seen.add(name)
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['Paul', 'is', '28', 'years', 'old.', 'Mary', 'is', '30', 'years', 'old.', 'Thomas', 'is', 'a', 'lawyer.', 'Smith', 'is', 'a', 'doctor']
```

[See Python Demo](https://ideone.com/FdJ7Fc)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without keeping track of seen words:

```
c = 'Paul is 28 years old. Mary is 30 years old. Paul is a lawyer. Mary is a doctor'
lst = c.split(' ')
d = {'Paul': 'Thomas','Mary':'Smith' }

for i, w in enumerate(lst):
    if w in d.keys() and lst.index(w) != i:
        lst[i] = d.get(w)

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['Paul', 'is', '28', 'years', 'old.', 'Mary', 'is', '30', 'years', 'old.', 'Thomas', 'is', 'a', 'lawyer.', 'Smith', 'is', 'a', 'doctor']
```

Or even better, you can replace the loop with this list comprehension:

```
[d.get(w) if w in d.keys() and lst.index(w) != i else w for i, w in enumerate(lst)]
```